# IBM SPSS How to import a Custom SQL Database Query

Tags: sql, spss

I am looking to see if the capability is there to have a custom SSMS sql query imported in SPSS (Statistical Package for the Social Sciences). I would want to build syntax that generates this query as my new dataset that I can then continue my scripted  analysis. I see the basic query capability of one table from a Sql Server but I would like to create a query that joins to many tables. I anticipate the query to be a bit complex with many joins and perhaps data transformations.

Has anybody had experience or a solution to this situation?

I know I could take the query and make a table of it that SPSS can then connect to but my data changes daily and I would need a job in another application to refresh this table before my SPSS syntax would pull it and I would like to eliminate that first step by just having the query that grabs the data at the beginning of my syntax.

Ultimately I am looking to build out my SPSS syntax and schedule it in the Production Facility to run daily.